# list produces specific set of combinations

Tags: c#, math, permutation, indexing

I have a C# list:

1. A
2. B
3. A
4. C
5. D
6. A

How can I find all the combinations of letters in which the index of the following letter is always bigger. So in this case, combinations could be: A, AB, ABA, C, CD, ADA... BUT NOT DC, CB... since B index comes before C index for last example. Using indexes, 1, 12, 123, 146, 134 would be accepted, but something like 143 would not be accepted since 4 is greater than 3.

Comment: I think that's because there are 3 `A`s in the list, so `ABA` is `123` (or `126`) and `ADA` is `156` (see indexes on the list above)

Comment: Is there a limit to the list length? Is there a limit to the length of each permutation? If you have tried something already please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate all nonempty subsets of set `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. For each such subset, just take its numbers (in increasing order) and convert them to the corresponding letters. This way you'll get all possible letter sequences. Then you'll have to remove duplicates, if necessary - for example `A` will be generated three times by sets `{1}`, `{3}` and `{6}`.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates all the combination ( as the sequence of list ) :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetCombination(new List<char> { 'A','B','C' });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void GetCombination(List<char> list)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, list.Count)); i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            string str = "";
            int j = Convert.ToInt32( Math.Pow(2, list.Count - 1));
            int index = 0;
            while (j > 0)
            {
                if (temp - j >= 0)
                {
                    str += list[index];
                    temp -= j;
                }
                j /= 2;
                index++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

And the output is :

```
C
B    
BC
A
AC
AB
ABC
```